# trying to send mysql info with php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I was wrestling with this a bit and could not get it figured out... I am using a mamp stack, I am trying to send a php email to multiple recipients, and having problems getting the database info sent with the email. In my php, I make a connection, pull the values from the database, then try to set variables equal to my database values. After that, I close the connection, then I get into the mail info... All I get sent to email is the letter "t". Any ideas how I can get this to output correctly?

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");
?><!--database connection-->

<?php //2. Perform db query

//specify the number of days to review

$days = 6 * 24;


$query = "SELECT d.memo ";
$query .= "FROM employee AS e, digital_memo AS d ";
$query .= "WHERE e.employee_id = d.employee_id AND ";
$query .= "d.time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . $days . " HOUR)";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$paragraph_markers = array("\n\n","\n");
$data = str_replace($paragraph_markers,'</p><p>',$data["memo"]);



?><!--query the database-->


<?php
include("close.php");
?>

<?php
$to = "barlowmitch@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = $data["memo"];
$from = "barlowmitch@hotmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

any ideas how I can connect the dots here?
thanks for any help!

Comment: include close.php after you have processed $data in your mail

Comment: Troubleshoot, troubleshoot, troubleshoot.  Print out your `$query`, your `$data` array, `$data`, and your `$message`.  Figure out what's wrong based on the values you get to see what's causing unexpected values.  Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already overwritten the $data variable here.

$data = str_replace($paragraph_markers,'

',$data["memo"]);

So naturally, the value for $data["memo"] is gone when you assign it to $message later on.

Comment: Its just a careless mistake. Usually if I encountered these unsolvable problems. I set it aside for a few hours, then relook at it with fresher eyes.